# PDO query is not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to run a simple SELECT query. here is the query

```
$sql1=$conn->prepare("SELECT q.quoteid, q.customername, q.customersurname, q.timestamp, o.name 
FROM quotes as q, occasions as o 
WHERE q.occasionid=o.occasionid 
AND companyid=1 
AND q.day=:day 
AND q.month=:month 
AND q.year=:year 
AND staffid='-1' 
AND (q.complete != 'W' OR q.complete != 'Y') 
AND q.online=0");
$sql1->execute($exearray);
/* here  $exearray contain following value */
Array ( [:day] => 24 [:month] => 1 [:year] => 2014 )
```

Its not even showing any error.
If I pass static value 1 in month it is showing data. 
I run this query directly on DB its working.

So I think there is no error in query. 
I am running this query locally on MAMP.

Comment: *"Its not even showing any error."* - Are you checking for them, and if so, how?

Comment: ...add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. If you're not already using that; it may help. 9 times out of 10, it does.

Comment: What if you execute the query inside a management invironment? phpmyadmin or mysqlbench? Do you get empty resultSet or an error? (You probably jsut get an empty result set, your WHERE statements are not right or there is just no data)

Comment: I am using try and catch to check errors. 
I tried 
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
and its not working

Comment: @joelharkes Data is there mate. I passed month value directly and it is showing data. there are around thousand rows for this where condition.

Comment: are you sure? did you insert all query parameters (not only month)? Are you also sure the JOIN is created the right way (by mysql)? Did you not make a typo anywhere else in code?

Comment: 100% sure mate. I echo the query text and run that directly on database and its working.

Comment: Did you know you first need to execute the query and then fetch the results?

Comment: TBH, I don't know much about JOINS, but am pretty sure you need to add the word `JOIN` in there somewhere, or `INNER JOIN`, or `LEFT JOIN`, something like that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Mysql can figure this out, based on foreign keys.

Comment: @joelharkes *Oh?!*. Hm... interesting.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It depends, it will work without joins as well. it is working if I don't include month in WHERE.

Comment: @HradayJoshi Hm... then maybe the column type is not correct? If it works for the others, then `month` may be a different type?

Comment: @HradayJoshi All you needed was a single date field, treating a date as  separate strings will just  complicate your life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In table month column type was Varchar.
I change that to integer and now it is working.

p.s. I have tried using (string) before variable and even double quotes and single quotes on variable value but it didn't work.

Thank you everyone. :)

Comment: [`Which is what I hinted...`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530686/pdo-query-is-not-working#comment41688910_26530686) but got no response from you. *You're welcome*.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to parse your month's data to string before passing to the pdo???

```
$exearray = array(':day'=>24, ':month'=>(string)1, ':year'=>2014);
```

once i faced this situation and i did this and it worked for me. 
i always have this problem while i trying to use LIMIT command in mysql. i just parse my value to string or pass it through statically.
and it doesn't relevant to your MAMP. i have this problem on LAMP and WAMP too.
apparently it's a common problem which it's in PDO libraries.

and for the record don't forget to use `intval()` while you pass your month's variable directly to your query.

Comment: don't be sad my friend, there is always a way. i suggest you to don't spend your time on it and use it directly with intval. although i have another way for you. and make a stored proc and calling it instead of writing your query in pdo. i did this one too and result was exactly what i expected. and it's safer than any solutions

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch your result, execute only returns a boolean (true or false) whether query execution succeeded or not.

Example:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

from: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: There is something wrong with month. because if I just pass year and day athen its working.
there is no typo as if I pass this query(with month) on DB it is working.
dont know what to do. :(

Comment: Could you show us your table structure? Can you script it to a CREATE script? This will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps doing it the "long-way" with the parameters, and/or changing the query to use a join would help.

Also, the try/catch on PDOException might provide more information.

Lastly, note the $cmd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) invoked for iterating through the recordset.

```
try {       
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8", "root", "root");
    $cmd = $db->prepare("
        SELECT q.quoteid, q.customername, q.customersurname, 
            q.timestamp, o.name 
        FROM quotes q
        LEFT JOIN occasions o on q.occasionid = o.occasionid
        WHERE companyid=1 
        AND q.day = :day 
        AND q.month = :month 
        AND q.year = :year 
        AND staffid = '-1' 
        AND (q.complete != 'W' OR q.complete != 'Y')    
        AND q.online = 0
    ");
    $cmd->bindParam(':day', 24, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $cmd->bindParam(':month', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $cmd->bindParam(':year', 2014, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if ($cmd->execute()) {
        while ($row = $cmd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $row['quoteid']."|".$row['customername']."|".$row['name']."<br/>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "$cmd->execute() returned false.";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); return; }
```